# default value of autocomplete with vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

so i make an signup and address form for every user and i want every time the user is connected and navigate to the profile page, he will edit his details.
now i have async autocomplete from api that get for me all the items in object format,
so i tried to give the v-model an default value but it didn't change, i guess there is supposed to be connection between the items to the v-model, so i tried to fake the async search and get the items but still couldn't see the default value.
i don't care if the value wont be in the data i just want to see it visual

```js
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    cmd: {
      type: String
    },
    itemText: {
      type: String
    },
    itemValue: {
      type: String
    },
    label: {
      type: String
    },
    city: {
      type: Number
    },
    street: {
      type: Number
    },
    type: {
      type: String
    },
    defaultValue: {
      type: String || Number
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      loading: false,
      items: [],
      search: null,
      select: null
    };
  },
  watch: {
    search(val) {
      val && val !== this.select && this.querySelections(val);
    },
    select(val) {
      if (val !== this.defaultValue) {
        this.$emit("selected", { value: val[this.itemValue], text: val[this.itemText] });
      }
    }
  },
  async mounted() {
    const defaultSelected = {};
    defaultSelected[`${this.itemText}`] = this.defaultValue ? this.defaultValue.value : this.defaultValue;
    defaultSelected[`${this.itemValue}`] = this.defaultValue ? this.defaultValue.id : this.defaultValue;
    await this.querySelections(defaultSelected[`${this.itemText}`]);
    console.log(this.items);
    // this.select = defaultSelected[`${this.itemText}`];
  },
  methods: {
    async querySelections(v) {
      this.loading = true;
      // Simulated ajax query
      const data = (await this.$services.SearchService.searchAddress(v, this.cmd, this.city, this.street)).data;
      console.log(data);

      if (this.type === "city") {
        this.items = data.Data[`CitiesRes`];
      }

      if (this.type === "street") {
        this.items = data.Data[`StreetsRes`];
      }

      if (this.type === "streetNumber") {
        this.items = data.Data["NumbersRes"];
      }
      this.loading = false;
    },
    asyncinsertDefualtData() {}
  }
};
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <v-autocomplete
    v-model="select"
    :loading="loading"
    :items="items"
    :search-input.sync="search"
    :item-text="itemText"
    :item-value="itemValue"
    :value="defaultValue"
    return-object
    cache-items
    flat
    hide-no-data
    hide-details
    solo
    :label="label"
  ></v-autocomplete>
</template>
```

Comment: try to also push whatever that you're putting in the `v-model` into the `items` array and it will probably show you the result you want. it's also completely ok to do because your `search-input.sync` will change your `items` array based on the input typed later on.

Comment: well it kinnda worked. i faked the search with the value i wanted and than insert the v-model the first value of the items

Comment: you kinda have to understand how `v-autocomplete` and its search works , in order for a value to be shown inside the selection slot you need to have that value in the `items` array ! also what you type inside the `input` will go to your `search` variable through `search-input.sync` and what you choose will be bound to `v-model`, since your `search` changes call the method that changes your `items` array , you can just load your data inside that `v-model` and push it inside `items` array , and it will work as expected without any problems. you don't really need any other extra steps. goodluck.